# Read patched attribute values from config files?

Tags: c#, configuration, sitecore, config, appsettings

I want to read the patched attributes that are in Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config to determine whether the Sitecore Item API is enable in my site. This value I'm looking for is itemwebapi.mode, and I want to see whether it's set to 'Off' or not.

```
<site name="mysite">
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">false</patch:attribute>
</site>
```

I tried getting `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["itemwebapi.mode"]` but it returns null. How do I get this value?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use **sitecore configuration factory** to read the configuration stuff.
 (http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Fundamentals/Sitecore%20Configuration%20Factory/#config_factory)

Try as below. If not working experiment in similar way.

```
var refObj = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("site/patch:attribute", true) as itemwebapi.mode;
```

If not useful, put a comment. I will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the attributes on the site node using the `Properties` accessor, 
if the attribute is not set then the value will be empty. For the current Context site:

```
string mode = Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["itemwebapi.mode"];
string access = Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["itemwebapi.access"];
string anon = Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess"];
```

If you are checking within an ItemWebApi request (beginning with `-/item/`) then you can check the `ItemWebApi.Context`:

```
if (Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Context.Current != null)
{
    Mode mode = Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Context.Current.Settings.Mode;
    AccessType access = Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Context.Current.Settings.Access;
    bool anon = Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Context.Current.Settings.AnonymousAcessAllowed;
}
```

This will give you strongly typed access to the settings using enums. Unfortunately the overloaded constructor for `RuntimeSettings()` is marked as internal so it is not possible to new this up yourself in a normal web request but could check the code and do something similar if you need.